# Auto-populated fields, Django forms on GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, django-forms

```
class Story(db.Model):
    title = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    slug = db.StringProperty(required=True)
```

I'm working with [Django's forms on Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/djangoforms.html).

I want to automatically generate a slug from a user-submitted title -- and then I want to validate that it exists. The slug doesn't have to be unique, it just has to exist.

Just making the `title` attribute required will cause a validation error if the title doesn't exist, but if the title is something like **###???** then my slug will be an empty string.

[This post](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/nov/02/django-tips-auto-populated-fields/) suggests using the model's `save` method, but the `save` method is called after validation has completed -- so it only works if you're slugifying a field that you know will turn into a valid slug.

I've tried two solutions, but neither one appeals to me, and I'm sure there's a better way to do it.

#### First

In the `title` field's `clean` method I slugified the title and then raised a `ValidationError` if a valid slug wasn't produced. This works pretty well and it's probably my best option so far.

The problem is I have to slugify the title *again* in the model's `save` method in order to generate a value for the slug field. This feels a little dirty.

#### Seccond

I made my `slug` field hidden with the widget `forms.HiddenInput` and then set the `slug` field's value to a generated slug *after* receiving the post data and *before* checking to see if the form is valid.

Unfortunately, when the slug doesn't exist in this scenario an error pops up that looks like this: `(Hidden field slug) My custom error message.` Django appends the first part (the stuff in parentheses) to my perfectly fine error message.

In order to get around this I sent the form to my template like this: `form.as_p().replace("Hidden field slug) ", "")`

But, again, this feels a little dirty.

#### ---

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [TransformProperty](http://github.com/Arachnid/aetycoon/blob/master/__init__.py#L141) from aetycoon:

```
class Story(db.Model):
    title = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    slug = aetycoon.TransformProperty(title, slugify, required=True)
```

Comment: But where should I return an error if the slug produced is an empty string? If I implement the TransformProperty and make the slug field hidden and required, I'll still have the problem in my second approach. (thanks for all of your help nick; you really do an excellent job keeping up with everything. it's amazing)

Comment: With the TransformProperty, you can take the first approach, set it to required, and it will throw an error if the slug is empty.